# Proving that $I+x$ is irreducible in $R/I$, where $R=k[x,y,z]$ and $I=\langle x^2-yz\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $K$ be a field and $I=\langle x^2-yz\rangle$. I am trying to prove that $R=K[x,y,z]/\langle x^2-yz\rangle$ is not a UFD.

My idea is that $(I+y)(I+z)=(I+x)^2$. But I am unable to prove that $I+x, I+y$ and $I+z$ are irreducibles in $R$.

How to prove their irreducibility?

Comment: Notice that $R/(y)\simeq k[x,z]/(x^2)$ and this last ring is not a domain. A similar argument shows that $I+x$ and $I+z$ are not irreducibles in $R$, indeed the quotients are not domains.

Comment: But $x^2-yz$ is irreducible in $K[x,y,z]$. Consider $K[x,y,z]=K[y,z][x]$. The element $y\in K[y,z]$ is prime. Hence, $x^2-yz$ is irreducible by the Eisenstein criterion. Therefore, the ideal generated by it is prime (since $K[x,y,z]$ is UFD and irreducibles are primes in UFD).

Comment: Of course, but the irriducibily of $x^2-yz$ doesn't imply the irriducibility of $x,y,z$ in $R$.

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro Your argument shows that $x,y,z$ are not *prime* in $R$. They are actually irreducible.